# .NET 6 Serilog is not creating log table

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, .net-6.0, serilog

I am trying to implement logging using serilog in one of my demo app (using .net 6). I am logging to sql database. I have kept "autoCreateSqlTable" to "true" in appSettings.json but serilog is not creating table in sql.

**appSettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=Test;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo" ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithClientIp", "WithClientAgent" ],
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "Server=Test;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
        "sinkOptionsSection": {
          "tableName": "LogsTable",          
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true          
        },
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
        "columnOptionsSection": {
          "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
          "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent", "SourceContext" ],
          "additionalColumns": [
            {
              "ColumnName": "ClientIP",
              "PropertyName": "ClientIp",
              "DataType": "nvarchar"
            }            
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


#region Configure serilog

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Serilog", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithClientIp()
                .Enrich.WithClientAgent()
                .CreateLogger();

Log.Logger = logger;
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
builder.Host.UseSerilog();

// Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));

#endregion


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Below are my nuget packages:

```
Serilog.AspNetCore - 6.0
Serilog.Settings.Configuration - 3.3.0
Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer - 5.7.1
Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo - 1.2.0
```

I tested the connection string and it is working fine but somehow serilog is not creating table. I am not understanding where I am going wrong.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: "Using":  ["Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"]?

Comment: There are two (different) connection strings in the appsettings.json file. Are you sure `"Server=Test;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"` works? What user is it logging in with?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am using same connection string. I am logging with Windows Authentication in sql.

Comment: One connection string has `Trusted_Connection=True;`, the other `Trusted_Connection=False;`. The first will be using Windows authentication to login. The second one should be throwing an exception because it's not using Windows authentication and neither have you supplied User ID and Password parameters for an SQL Login.

Comment: Hey @AlwaysLearning I have updated my question and changed the Trusted_Connection to True in serilog property but still it is not creating table. I am using windows authentication only.

Comment: @MihalBy I tried "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ], still serilog not creating table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your appsettings.json.

using,enrich and other sections are out of serilog section:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=Test;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Enrichers.ClientInfo","Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
      }
    },
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithClientIp", "WithClientAgent" ],
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "Server=Test;Database=TestDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
        "sinkOptionsSection": {
          "tableName": "LogsTable",          
          "autoCreateSqlTable": true          
        },
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
        "columnOptionsSection": {
          "primaryKeyColumnName": "Id",
          "addStandardColumns": [ "LogEvent", "SourceContext" ],
          "additionalColumns": [
            {
              "ColumnName": "ClientIP",
              "PropertyName": "ClientIp",
              "DataType": "nvarchar"
            }            
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey @CodingMytra, good catch. Thank you so much, it is working now. Just a small question, in the "WriteTo" node, I have a property called "connectionString" and at the very top there is one more "ConnectionStrings" property, my connection string is going to be the same. So is there a way in json to declare something at one place and use it at different places in the same json file?

Comment: yes it is possible, just specify the "DefaultConnection"(for your case) in place of complete connection string in Args section.